# snmp v1 trap not reaching mib browser trap listener

Tags: snmp, mib, snmp4j

I have a snmp4j trap sender and I am trying to send trap to mib browser. I can see packet reaching in wireshark on the machine where trap listener is running. But mib browser tool trap listener not able to get it.

Code for sending trap:

```
TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
transport.listen();
CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version1);
target.setAddress(snmpManagerAddress);
target.setTimeout(5000);
target.setRetries(2);
PDUv1 pdu = new PDUv1();
pdu.setType(PDU.V1TRAP);
pdu.setEnterprise(new OID(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.8"));
pdu.setGenericTrap(PDUv1.ENTERPRISE_SPECIFIC);
pdu.setSpecificTrap(1);
pdu.setAgentAddress(new IpAddress("aa.bb.cc.ddd"));
snmp.send(pdu, target);
snmp.close();
logger_.info("Sent trap to client");
```

Comment: Since Wireshark confirms the packet arrived, it is no longer a fault in your code in most cases. Possible causes can be, 1) another application caught the packet before the MIB browser (on Windows it can be the Windows trap listener); 2) the MIB browser itself decides to drop the packet. That's more of a configuration issue right now.

Comment: I tried various configuration with MIB browser but still not able to see the packet. I am running snmp manager on windows server 2008 and it has snmp trap stopped by default so it can't be intercepting the packets before it reaches mib browser.